# need Regular expression for parsing code

Tags: php, parsing, expression

i have css file and need to pares style like

```
#x{ a:b;c:d;}
```

that is good , but there style like

```
@media pla pla {
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
}
```

this style i can't know how i write Regular expression for it , i need result like this

```
$x(0) = @media pla pla
$(1) =#x{ a:b;c:d;}
      #x{ a:b;c:d;}
      #x{ a:b;c:d;}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot parse CSS using Regular Expressions because CSS's grammar is not a classified as a "[Regular Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)".

Comment: A full blown compiler compiler such as lex/yacc, flex/bison, ANTLR, etc. could possibly handle it (if it can run under PHP), but would probably be overkill for CSS. To use just PHP's preg calls, you would have to construct a parser yourself, using regexps to recognize pieces of it, but doing much of the work yourself.

Comment: i create compressor css with this code  preg_match_all('/\@import[^\;]*\;/', $cssx, $p);     return str_ireplace('imagedata', 'url(data:', str_ireplace('url(/template/' . $_FCSSILE . '/images/http://', 'url(http://', str_ireplace('{}', '{ }', str_ireplace('url(', 'url(/template/' . $_FCSSILE . '/images/', str_ireplace('url(data:', 'imagedata', str_ireplace(array('; ', ' }', '{ ', ': ', ' {', '  '), array(';', '}', '{', ':', '{', ' '), str_ireplace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  '), ' ', preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', ' ', $cssx))))))));

Comment: need to know how i can pares from x{ y { z } { zz } } last }} i cant get coz there are one or more close sign } between x and }}

Comment: @Dai What part does make CSS irregular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave it a try using extended regex with a [recursive pattern](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) more for interest and practice :)

```
$code = '

#x{ a:b;c:d;}

@media pla pla {
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
  #x{ a:b;c:d;}
}

#z{ a:b;c:d;}';

// --------------------------

// remove comments first, if there are
#$code = preg_replace('~/\*.*?\*/~s', "", $code);

// try it with a recursive pattern
$recursive_pattern = '~(?:^|\n)\s*\K[^\s{][^{]*?\s*{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}~';

$result = array();
if(preg_match_all($recursive_pattern, $code, $out))
{
  foreach($out[0] AS $k => $v)
  {
    // break into -> start { inner }
    if(preg_match('~^([^{]+?)\s*{\s*(.*?)\s*}\s*$~s', $v, $out2))
    {
      // set inner -> trim/expand spaces
      $result[$out2[1]] = ltrim(preg_replace(

          //    |start sp |newline   |;} -> ; }       | 2+ spaces -> 1
          array('~^ +~m', '~\r?\n~', '~;(?=[^\s])~m', '~\s{2,}~'),
          array("",       " ",       "; ",            " "),
          $out2[2]));
    }
  }
}

// check output
echo "<pre>"; var_export($result); echo "</pre>";
```

*output*:

```
array (
  '#x' => 'a:b; c:d;',
  '@media pla pla' => '#x{ a:b; c:d; } #x{ a:b; c:d; } #x{ a:b; c:d; }',
  '#z' => 'a:b; c:d;',
)
```

*Short explanation*:

- `(?:^|\n)` At string start or newline
- `\s*` any amount of white-spaces
- `\K` reset beginning of match
- `[^\s{][^{]*?` one character, that's no white-space or `{` followed by as few of any that are no `{`
- `\s*` followed by any amount of white-spaces
- `\{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}` recursive part: match a `{` followed by any amount of characters, that are not `{}` or `(R)` start over the whole thing... `}`

Comment: code = '
#a{ a:1;a:2;}
@media {
  #b{ b:1;b:2; }
  #c{ c:1;c:2; }
  #d{ d:1;c:2; }
} 
#z{ z:1;z:2;}'; result =  array (
  '#a' => 'a:1;a:2;',
  '#d' => 'd:1;c:2; }',
  '#z' => 'z:1;z:2;',
)

Comment: i try this $recursive_pattern = '~(?:^|\n)\s*[^{]+?\s*{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}~'; and its work , thank you :)